# Circuit breaker on Spring JMSListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I have many services that are annotated with the @HystrixCommand annotation. Up to now, they were called from a bean that implemented the MessageListener interface.

Now, I want to call these same services from a bean that is annotated with @JmsListener. I want this bean to be aware of failures in the called services, so it stops consuming messages from the queue.

My question is: How do I have to annotate this listener bean, to indicate the hystrix command keys that should make the listener stop consuming messages.

Or putting it more broadly: How do I make the listener to stop reading messages from the queue, once one of the invoked services fail (And how do I restart it again after a timeout)